# I am getting unable to compile TypeScript error TS1005: ',' expected, but can't figure out why

Tags: typescript

I am working on trying out and example for prisma.io and using one of the examples I get an error complaining about wanting a `,` and I can't figure out why.  Here is the code:

```
const Profile = objectType({
  name: 'Profile',
  definition(t) {
    t.nonNull.int('id')
    t.string('bio')
    t.field('user', {
      type: 'User',
      resolve: (parent, _, context) => {
        return context.prisma.profile
          .findUnique({
            where: { id: parent.id || undefined },
          })
          .user()
      },
    })
  },
})

const User = objectType({
  name: 'User',
  definition(t) {
    t.nonNull.int('id')
    t.string('name')
    t.nonNull.string('email')
    t.nonNull.list.nonNull.field('posts', {
      type: 'Post',
      resolve: (parent, _, context: Context) => {
        return context.prisma.user
          .findUnique({
            where: { id: parent.id || undefined },
          })
          .posts()
      },
      t.field ('profile',{
        type: 'Profile',
        resolve: (parent,_,context) =>{
          return context.prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: {id: parent.id}
          }).profile()
        },
      })
    })
  },
})
```

I get the following error when it tries to compile the code:

```
[ERROR] 09:24:23 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/schema.ts:263:8 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

263       t.field ('profile',{
           ~
```

It seems to want it in position 8, but doesn't make sense. Any help is appreciated.  I'm not a developer just trying to work through this example from their github.

Comment: A function call is now legal inside an object literal. What the code *should* do instead I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error.

It's because it's a `t.field(...)` is a function call that evaluates to a value, and you placed this value within an object literal declaration where it is expecting a list of fields. The error will go away when you assign the function call to a field name. Below I've annotated your code with 's and comments, and assigned the function call value to "species". That may not be what you want, but it helps you understand the syntax error.

```js
const User = objectType({
  name: 'User',
  definition(t) {
    t.nonNull.int('id')
    t.string('name')
    t.nonNull.string('email')
    t.nonNull.list.nonNull.field('posts', {  // opening brace of object literal
      type: 'Post',  // field "type"
      resolve: (parent, _, context: Context) => {  // field "resolve"
        return context.prisma.user
          .findUnique({
            where: { id: parent.id || undefined },
          })
          .posts()
      },
      species: t.field ('profile',{  // field "species"
        type: 'Profile',
        resolve: (parent,_,context) =>{
          return context.prisma.user.findUnique({
            where: {id: parent.id}
          }).profile()
        },
      })
    })  // closing brace of the object literal
  },
})
```

Comment: Probably `t.field` should be outside the object literal, since that's where all the other uses of `t` occur.

Comment: @kaya3 yeah probably. But they only needed the error explained. Who knows what this code does 

Comment: @Eric-Pratt the norm is to upvote the answer as well as accept ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs in the middle of defining an object literal so you need to provide field name before t.field, eg foo:

```
{
            type: 'Post',
            resolve: (parent, _, context: Context) => {
                return context.prisma.user
                    .findUnique({
                        where: { id: parent.id || undefined }
                    })
                    .posts()
            },
            foo: t.field('profile', {
                type: 'Profile',
                resolve: (parent, _, context) => {
                    return context.prisma.user
                        .findUnique({
                            where: { id: parent.id }
                        })
                        .profile()
                }
            })
        }
```